# Declarations of a class name and a variable with the same name

Tags: c++, declaration

The Standard `N4296::3.3.1/4 [basic.scope.declarative]`:

> *exactly one* declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name
>   that is not a typedef name and the other declarations shall all refer
>   to the same variable or enumerator, or all refer to functions and
>   function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is
>   hidden (3.3.10).

I understand that the rule is talking about hiding the name of the class if there is a variable/function declaration with the same name in the same declrartive region. But the the *exactly one* is a bit confusing. The following namespace is perfectly valid:

```
namespace A
{
    struct A;
    struct A { };
    int A;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/662d588ebd77a21b)**

although we declared the `struct A` twice (two declarations of a struct and one of a variable). What's wrong? What did I lose in the rule?

Comment: I think it's intended to ban things like `struct A { int x; }; enum A { y };`, but the wording is a bit too restrictive.

Comment: You did not in fact declare the struct twice: "A declaration consisting solely of _class-key identifier;_ is either a redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward declaration of the identifier as a class name."

Comment: "A declaration consisting solely of *class-key identifier*; is either a redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward delaration of the identifier as a class name" is in [\[class.name\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Exactly one class may have the name:
struct A; // Declaration of a new class.
struct A { }; // Definition, but not a declaration of a new name. Doesn't count.

// Aside from the class, exactly one variable may share the name:
extern int A; // Declaration of a variable.
int A; // Definition of a variable.
```

Comment: Why doesn't `struct A { };` count?

Comment: @T.C. It's not declaring something new. It's syntactically a *declaration* but it's not "declaring a name." Perhaps *introduce* would be a better word, to match [basic] §3/5.

Comment: Yes, I think we all agree that it *shouldn't* count, but I don't think you can reach the conclusion that it *does not* count from the standard as written.

Comment: @T.C. I agree that there may be a defect, as far as I've read, and I think that substituting "introduce" could remedy it. (Class-names may be introduced by elaborated-type-specifiers as well, so it should perhaps be "At most one … shall be introduced," without mentioning declarations per se.) However, there's more text to review before I'd actually file a DR, and I don't have a plan to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`struct A;` is a declaration.  However, `struct A { };` is a *definition*.

Comment: A definition is a declaration.